# Jest branch code coverage - problem with nullable values

Tags: jestjs, code-coverage

At first glance problem looks really easy, but unfortunately I have a problem with covering test scenario when nullable getter is null. Considering the sample below:

```
@Component({
selector: 'sample-form-test',
templateUrl: './sample-form-test.component.html'
})
export class SampleFormTestComponent implements ngOnInit {

form?: FormGroup;

get name(): FormControl | null {
   return this.form?.get('name') as FormControl;
}

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilderService) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.form = this.formBuilder.build();
}
```

It is always underlined in a code coverage report that the question mark inside the getter above is not covered by the tests. Even if I try to cover it by checking directly whether is that getter null right after a component creation:

```
describe('create SampleFormTestComponent', () => {

   let spectator = Spectator<SampleFormTestComponent>; // from @ngneat/Spectator
   const createComponent = createComponentFactory({ // from @ngneat
      component: SampleFormTestComponent,
      providers: MockProvider(FormBuilderService, {
         build: () => {
            new FormGroup({name: new FormControl})
         }
      }
   });  
 
   it('should create', () => {
      spectator = createComponent();
      expect(spectator).toBeTruthy();

      expect(spectator.component.name).toBeNull(); 
   });
}
```

It doesn't help at all and branch coverage is always lowered by that nullable getters. The worst scenario is when I have them multiple inside the class - in that scenario it is not possible to meet code coverage requirements. Do you know how can I easily solve that problem?

**UPDATE**

The easiest way is to initialize form in a constructor – it will allow to access the form properties (even if those are empty) without necessity to check if those values are null ot not.

```
@Component({
selector: 'sample-form-test',
templateUrl: './sample-form-test.component.html'
})
export class SampleFormTestComponent implements ngOnInit {

form: FormGroup;

get name(): FormControl {
   return this.form.get('name') as FormControl;
}

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilderService) {
   this.form = this.formBuilder.build();
}
```

[Here is the updated Stackblitz solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2sagme?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Under what circumstances would `this.loanForm` be undefined?

Comment: It is a `loanBuilderService` method called inside the ngOnInit() hook (responsible for creating form). Until then the form should be null.

Comment: Please [edit] to provide a [mre] explaining what you're testing and how you're testing it.

Comment: I provided code changes, now the code should be clearer. Also here is the stackblitz solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2sagme?file=package.json

Comment: My first suggestions would be: create the form in the constructor so it doesn't need to be optional, and/or don't have arbitrary coverage requirements.

Comment: Indeed, it can be a solution:).